# SQL query to group transactions by month

Tags: mysql, sql

```
----------------------------------------
|transaction_id|customer_id|month|value|
----------------------------------------
```

I am looking for a SQL query that would return customers ID of the customers that had more transactions in the month of October instead of November or of customers that ONLY had transactions in November (and none in October). The month column is of type string (not a date)

I was thinking an inner join could do it, but past that I do not know how to approach this problem.

This is what I attempted

```
select customer_id
from tbl_name
where (select count(month is 'October') > count(month is 'November') from tbl_name)
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this yourself? Show the code.

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: I have attempted it but I know for a fact its wrong. I thought of using a subquery where I would retrieve the counts for month in October and November for each customer_id and compare them and check if one is higher than the other

Comment: With SQL questions you should always tag your DBMS (MySQL or SQL Server or whichever).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You count records. So you aggregate. You want counts per customer_id. So you'd **group by** customer_id. You forgot this in your query.

Then you'd compare the counts in the `HAVING` clause, i.e. after having counted October and November records.

```
select customer_id
from tbl_name
where month in ('October', 'November')
group by customer_id
having count(case when month = 'October' then 1 end) >
       count(case when month = 'November' then 1 end)
    or count(case when month = 'October' then 1 end) = 0;
```

You don't need to access the table twice as you see. Just aggregate and see what you have :-)

Comment: Thanks!, how could I also print a customer_id for customers that only bought stuff in November? I think this will only print a customer_id if they have more in October

Comment: You are right, I forgot about this. One simple way is to add criteria with `OR`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Well, I just noticed that I'd add `where month in ('October', 'November')`. So we'd avoid unnecessary evaluations and could also get the having clause simpler.

Comment: Do you mean before the having block? From your new edit, wouldn't we only enter that block if the where statement is true (we have purchases in both months)

Comment: I've updated my answer accordingly. Yes, `WHERE` comes before `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, i.e. before aggregation.

Comment: BTW: In MySQL true is 1 and false is 0. So if you like to, you can replace the standard SQL `count(case when month = 'October' then 1 end)` with `sum(month = 'October')` which is only valid in MySQL.

Comment: Right but my question is, with the where clause, would we not only look for records with months in october and november? What if we are looking at an id with records ONLY in november?

Comment: No, a record can not be both in October and November. A record has one value in the month column which is either October or November or something else. `where month in ('October', 'November')` is the same as `month = 'October' or month = 'November'`, only more readable.